# How to read a hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a hashtable with the below values,

```
$jumpHash = @{3 = {"JumpPC-1", "JumpPC-3", "JumpPC-5"}; 2 = {"JumpPC-2", "JumpPC-4"} }
```

I want to read the values of keys(2 & 3) and to apply it in `-Name` off `Import-VApp` command

```
    $jumpHash.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
      Import-VApp -Source $jumphostpath -Name $_.Key -DiskStorageFormat Thin -VMHost $vmshost -Datastore $storage
}
```

Please suggest a way to read all the values of each key and to pass the value in *-Name* attribute

Comment: This `$hostHash = @{3 = (JumpPC-1, JumpPC-3, JumpPC-5)} ; 2 = (JumpPC-2, JumpPC-4)}` is not valid code, please update your question

Answer (score 0):

Due the lack of information this answer is untested, but it loops through the hosthash and places the results into -Name

```
$jumpHash = @{3 = { "JumpPC-1", "JumpPC-3", "JumpPC-5" }; 2 = { "JumpPC-2", "JumpPC-4" } }

$jumpHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
$_.value.ToString().split(',') | Foreach-Object {
    Import-VApp -Source $jumphostpath -Name $_ -DiskStorageFormat Thin -VMHost $vmshost -Datastore $storage
}
```

}

Please supply a proper hash table next time. The content of $jumpHash would also be usefull, so we can run the actual code.

Comment: I have edited the hashtable accordingly, values of $jumpHash also added. 
Here is the value of $jumpHash = @{3 = ("JumpPC-1", "JumpPC-3", "JumpPC-5"); 2 = ("JumpPC-2", "JumpPC-4") }
please ignore the variable $hosthash

Comment: @Iterator Since $hosthash and $jumphash turned out to be the same, i removed the second foreach-object.

Comment: Received the below traceback:
Import-VApp : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At C:\TestHashtablescript.ps1:64 char:43
+   Import-VApp -Source $jumphostpath -Name $_.Value -DiskStorageFormat ...

Comment: Added another little loop that splits the values.

Comment: Not sure about the `Import-VApp` cmdlet, but I think you may want to use `-Name $_.Trim('" ')` to get rid of the quotes and extra spaces around the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jumpHash = @{3 = @("JumpPC-1", "JumpPC-3", "JumpPC-5"); 2 = @("JumpPC-2", "JumpPC-4")}

2..3 | % {$jumpHash[$_] | % {$_}} | Import-VApp
```